# Error when creating AD contacts with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have this script to create new contacts, but the import this time around is giving me an error saying, "Multiple values were specified for an attribute that can only have one value." While I understand the error, I don't have a solution to determine that attribute that gives me the problem. I've tried to review the XML file, but it's long, and I don't see multiple values per attribute. Could anyone assist?

```
    # ...
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$import = Import-Clixml ""
$potentialAttributes = @(
    'givenName'
    'sn'
    'mail'
    'displayName'
    'cn'
    'co'
    'company'
    'l'
    'mailNickname'
    'telephoneNumber'
    'st'
    'streetAddress'
    'postalcode'
    'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    'mobile'
    'department'
    'title'
    'targetaddress'
    'proxyAddresses'
)

foreach($contact in $import){
    $newContact=@{
        path      = "OU=Contacts,DC=A"
        type      = "Contact"
        Name      = $contact.name
        OtherAttributes = @{}
    }

    foreach($attributeName in $potentialAttributes){
        if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($contact.$attributeName)){
            $newContact['OtherAttributes'][$attributeName] = $contact.$attributeName
        }
    }
    
    New-ADObject @newContact
}
```

Example XML

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="7">
    <TN RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <S N="name">Person, A (Company)</S>
      <S N="proxyAddresses">SMTP:A.person@company.com</S>
      <S N="givenName">A</S>
      <S N="sn">Person</S>
      <S N="mail">A.person@company.com</S>
      <S N="displayName">Person, A (Company)</S>
      <S N="cn">Person, A</S>
      <Nil N="co" />
      <S N="company">ABC</S>
      <Nil N="l" />
      <Nil N="mailnickname" />
      <Nil N="telephoneNumber" />
      <Nil N="st" />
      <Nil N="streetAddress" />
      <Nil N="postalcode" />
      <Nil N="physicalDeliveryOfficeName" />
      <Nil N="mobile" />
      <Nil N="department" />
      <Nil N="title" />
      <Nil N="targetaddress" />
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: We can't assist you with reviewing the XML without _seeing the XML_ :)

Comment: I added a sample above.

Comment: You can't set `cn` as a separate attribute, it'll be derived from the object's name

Comment: You are correct. That seems to be the solution. Odd, I previously included CN, and the script worked for all my other contacts.

Comment: It's possible that the DSA _ignores_ it if the name and cn values are exactly the same - but that doesn't appear to be the case in the sample you've posted. In any case, safest option is to provide a correct name and skip `cn` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflicting attribute here is the `CN`.

The CN (or common-name) attribute is the RDN (*relative distinguished name*) attribute for the `contacts` schema, and it's value will automatically be derived from the object's *name* (which you've already provided) on creation.

Skip the `cn` attribute completely:

```
$potentialAttributes = @(
    'givenName'
    'sn'
    'mail'
    'displayName'
    'co'
    'company'
    'l'
    'mailNickname'
    'telephoneNumber'
    'st'
    'streetAddress'
    'postalcode'
    'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    'mobile'
    'department'
    'title'
    'targetaddress'
    'proxyAddresses'
)
```